# How to enter data into TGrid Cells in C++ Builder or Delphi

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey, tgrid

I have some difficulties in entering some data into TGrid Cells, can someone give me some code example with commentary on how to insert data into a TGrid cell? To be more precise in C++ Builder when I'm using a StringGrid I can use

```
StringGrid1->Cells[1][0] = "Hello world";
```

which will insert in the cell of the second column of the first row the "hello world" message. How can I do the same with TGrid? And how can I use TCheckColumn? I have many diffulties because I cannot find any good documentation.
I'm looking but there is no guide on this anywhere.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/TGrid_(Delphi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firemonkey: TGrid usage on Embarcadero C++ Builder XE3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543698/firemonkey-tgrid-usage-on-embarcadero-c-builder-xe3)

Comment: This helped me a lot [MonkeyStyler](http://monkeystyler.com/guide/TGrid)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:
You need to store the data in your own data structure, and pass it to the displayed grid via the `OnGetValue` event.

---

I found the answer in the [link to MonkeyStyler](http://monkeystyler.com/guide/TGrid) provided by @nolaspeaker in the comments.

> TGrid does not store any data internally.

You need to store the data yourself. When a cell in your grid is displayed, the `OnGetValue(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer; var Value: TValue)` event is fired.

It is up to you to implement an event handler for this, and return the data for the given cell.

For example, suppose you have a very simple grid that only shows "hello" in every cell of the first column and "world" in every cell of the second column.
Your `OnGetValue` event would look like this:

```
procedure MyOnGetValueHandler(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer; var Value: TValue);
begin
  if Col = 0 then
    Value := 'hello'
 else 
 if Col = 1 then
    Value := 'world';
end;
```